Laravel API authentication: Sanctum + Breeze
I just started a new Laravel application.
For API authentication I installed Sanctum and it seems working right: testing API route authentication in feature tests using Sanctum::actingAs() assert expected 401 and 200 response codes.
Then I added Breeze with VueJs: login works correctly, but I have problems on API authentication.
Sanctum states that for SPA authentication, more precisely for CSRF protection, I need to make a first request to /sanctum/csrf-cookie so I added this call via axios in Breeze login page with
onMounted(() => {
    axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
});

and this too seems to work fine: call is made and a 204 response is returned.
Then for login I need to make a POST to /login in order to have Laravel authenticate subsequent calls via the session cookie issued to the client: this call is already successfully made by Breeze login page, but when calling a sanctum-protected api route I get an 401 response.
Am I missing something?
